# Rows to columns in MySQL without knowing the rows in advance

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I have a MySQL table that looks like this:

```
 +---------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
| truckNo | excavatorId | times_loaded | litres      | litres/time |
+---------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
|  1      | 345         | 100          |          50 |         0.5 |
+---------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
|  1      | 275         | 34           |          50 |        1.47 |  
+---------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
|  2      | 275         | 100          |          50 |         0.5 |
+---------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
```

In this table, an Excavator loads to any truck one or more times. For example Excavator 345 loaded some material on truck 1 100 times. But Truck 1 was also loaded by excavator 275 some material 34 times.  Now I want to group the results per truck, so in the left column I can see the distinct truck and have each excavator as a new column as in the following table:

```
 +--------+---------------------------------+---------------+--------------+
 |  Truck |     Excavators    | Total_loads |  Total litres |  Litres/load |
 +--------+-----------+-------+-------------+---------------+--------------+
 |        |    345    |  275  |             |               |              |
 +--------+-----------+-------+-------------+---------------+--------------+
 |    1   |    100    |  34   |   134       |     1.95      |    0.01      |
 +--------+-----------+-------+-------------+---------------+--------------+
 |    2   |           |  50   |   50        |     50        |    1         |
 +--------+-----------+-------+-------------+---------------+--------------+
```

The problem is that I never know in advance how many excavators will there be in the table so I know how many columns to make.
Is there any way to do that ? Is it possible is SQL ?

**EDIT:** Each truck is loaded one or more times by any excavator. So in the result table for example truck no 1 was loaded 100 times by Excavator 345 and 34 times by excavator 275. In total loads you see all loads that were upon truck 1, from all/any excavator which is 134. Same for liters. The litres/load is the division in the result table of Total litres / Total_loads

Comment: I don't get the result set.  It doesn't look related to the sample data.

Comment: Assuming you know all possible excavatorIds (275 and 345) - What would be your query?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: @GordonLinoff check my edit

Comment: Why does excavator 275 not show for truck 2 in the second table, is that a typo?

Comment: This kind of data-driven pivot operation is very difficult, if not impossible, in pure MySQL. Consider taking @Strawberry’s advice.

Comment: @SEarle1986 it does. You see this 50 under 34 in the third column? This means track 2 was loaded 50 times by Excavator 275. BUT truck 2 was NOT loaded by Excavator 345 at all. That's why it's empty there

Comment: As others have said, this is a presentation layer problem and therefore should be addressed in presentation layer code (PHP etc..)

Comment: There are typos in your results. It must be 100 loads for truck 2 and 100 litres for truck 1 and litres/load must be adjusted accordingly. As to `litres/time`: Don't store data redundantly in a database table, you can always calculate this value by dividing `litres` by `times_loaded`.

Answer (score 0):

SQL queries always generate result tables with the columns stated. If you don't know the columns you want to show, you cannot write the query.

Your options:

1. Select the raw data and construct the result table from that data in your app or Website.
2. Select the excavators first. Then use your programming language to create a query particularly for those excavators.
3. Do with one column containing concatenated strings.

Here is #3:

```
select
  truckno,
  group_concat('EX(', excavatorid, ')=', times_loaded order by excavatorid) as loads,
  sum(times_loaded) as total_loads,
  sum(litres) as total_litres,
  sum(litres) / sum(times_loaded) as litres_per_load
group by truckno
order by truckno;
```